# How to horizontally orient a bar plot in plotly using python?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a bar plot that resembles this something like this-

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
months = ["ABC","XYZ"]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=months,
    y=[3.95,4.04],
    name='SMD',
    marker_color='yellow'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=months,
    y=[3.78,4.06],
    name='Camrest',
    marker_color='black'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=months,
    y=[4.16,4.28],
    name='MWOZ 2.1',
    marker_color='cadetblue'
))

fig.update_layout(barmode='group', template="plotly_white")

fig.show()
```

I would like to anti-clockwise rotate the bar plot by 45 degrees, that is, horizontally orient the bar graph. How can I achieve this?

Also, how can I add a custom label to the y-axis as it currently only has the number scale and no axis name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A horizontal bar graph can be created by reversing the x- and y-axes of a normal bar graph and specifying the graph direction. In addition, the y-axis is reversed. Refer to this in [the official reference](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-bar-charts/#horizontal-bar-chart-with-gobar).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
months = ["ABC","XYZ"]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    y=months,
    x=[3.95,4.04],
    name='SMD',
    marker_color='yellow',
    orientation='h'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    y=months,
    x=[3.78,4.06],
    name='Camrest',
    marker_color='black',
    orientation='h'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    y=months,
    x=[4.16,4.28],
    name='MWOZ 2.1',
    marker_color='cadetblue',
    orientation='h'
))

fig.update_layout(barmode='group', template="plotly_white", yaxis=dict(autorange='reversed'))

fig.show()
```

[image]